# Почему у меня не работает аннотация @PreRemove?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, юнит-тесты, h2

Пишу интеграционные тесты для сервисов с базой в памяти (h2). Сервисы не содержат никакой логики и просто вызывают аналогичные методы у ДАО. Также на сервисах стоят аннотации `@Transactional` (на уровне классов). Методы для чтения в сервисах помечены аннотациями `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`.
Сейчас тестирую сервис для работы со справочником. Сама сущность справочника помечена аннотациями: `@Entity`, `@Immutable`, `@EntityListeners(PreventAnyUpdate.class)`.

```
public class PreventAnyUpdate {
    @PrePersist
    void onPrePersist(Object o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't create Entity!");
    }

    @PreRemove
    void onPreRemove(Object o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't delete Entity");
    }
}
```

Все тесты проходят, кроме тестов для `delete()`. Должен выбрасывать исключение, но не выбрасывает, а всё нормально удаляет (что вообще не должен делать). Что не так?